# ios simulator British Summer Time wrong hour

Tags: objective-c, ios-simulator, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to parse a date from a String and get an NSDate:

```
NSArray *expld_date = [day componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSString * keyword = [[[expld_date objectAtIndex:1]
                                                stringByAppendingString: @"/"]
                                                      stringByAppendingString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", year] ];

NSDate * date = [_dateFormatter dateFromString: keyword];

NSLog( @"Other Date string %@", keyword );
NSLog( @"Other Date %@", date );

Other Date string 14/07/2013
Other Date 2013-07-13 23:00:00 +0000
```

Is this supposed to be happening, or is my simulator wrong? I assumed it received the same date-time as the host computer.

Comment: `NSDate` does not contain timezone information, which is why it *looks* to be an hour out in this case. You should read [the date and time reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039i) in the documentation.

Comment: @Petesh so I should not use NSDate if I want the Summer time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `[NSDate date]` it just returns the date. It does not apply a NSDateFormatter to it, which is what is needed to display it in local timezone.

The time is correct, based on the fact that `BST` is 1 hour forward of `GMT`

Comment: Please explain this to me, as I don't get it. I've loaded from string, set the format, then tried to load new NSDate with formatter. Will I still not be able to get the correct date-time?